# Jupyter Notebook Add Project Path

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to know if I can configure jupyter notebooks so I can set the path to a development folder?

I know I can do this:

`import sys
sys.path.append("/foo/project/bar")`

but I don't want to have to do this for every project/notebook, etc...

I was examining the config.py file, but I am unsure of what I need to change.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [%cd](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=magic%20commands#magic-cd) line magic.